# Multiple citations with just one pair of braces

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

I want to have multiple citations appear in my exported PDF as below:

```
some well-studied fact [12, 13, 20] blah blah
```

But the only way I know to do this is by using inline latex:

```
some well-studied fact \cite{foo2002, bar1997, baz2019}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result using the more "org" style citation:

```
some well-studied fact [cite:foo2002, cite:bar1997, cite:baz2019]
```

Note: the above results in this export:

```
some well-studied fact [[1], [2], [3]]
```

...which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
some well-studied fact [[cite:foo2002,bar1997,baz2019]]
```

That is, mulitple cite labels within a single org link. Note the double [[...]] although if you simply type cite:xxx it should make it an org link automatically.